# Spring server.address=localhost cannot connect from Node.js fetch api

Tags: node.js, spring, hosts

I have solved this, but I still don't know why.

I have a Spring Boot server when I set "server.address=localhost", the server cannot connect any more from Node.js fetch API. But using web browser is okay, and when commenting "::1  localhost" line in the host file is okay too.

What is the reason for this problem?

When I request with "localhost:8082/xxxx", the error occurred:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8082/api/auth/test")
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

```
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.processResponse (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6277:34)
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6602:42
    at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)
    at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8082
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1247:16) {
    errno: -61,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '::1',
    port: 8082
  }
}
```

If I use `curl http://localhost:8082/api/auth/test`, everything is okay, like this:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8082...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8082 (#0)
> GET /api/auth/test HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8082
> User-Agent: curl/7.88.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 
< Vary: Origin
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 0
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 11
< Date: Wed, 09 Aug 2023 09:52:05 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
test ok 123%
```

I have another try and found something new, If I config `application.properties` in spring, the request with "localhost" will be failed and get above error. If I don't config this, it will be okay.

I use `fetch` like this, and this fetch is in a pure nodejs project:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8080/test")
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

Comment: This question is rather sparse at the moment. Could you edit this question to show any logs from the client and the listener? Also, perhaps you could add in the console output of a curl fetch, with `-vvv` verbose flags added?

Comment: @halfer I have added more info.

Comment: Are you perhaps doing the `fetch()` from a Docker container? The results you are presenting are indeed odd, I can't think why curl would behave differently.

Comment: Ah, the error looks like you might be connecting in IPv6 mode in Node, maybe `curl` auto-selects the protocol, and falls back to IPv4? Does `fetch()` have an IPv4 force mode, which you can use even without a dotted quad?

Comment: You say that when you remove "::1 localhost"from the hosts file, `fetch()` starts working. I wonder if this partially gets IPv6 working, but there is another problem with it. So by removing it, you indicate to `fetch()` that it should use IPv4, and it works in the way that `curl` does.

Comment: If you try `curl -vvv`, does it show you IPv4/6 selection logic?

Comment: @halfer *   Trying 127.0.0.1:8082...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8082 (#0)
> GET /api/auth/test HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8082
> User-Agent: curl/7.88.1

There is no ipv6.

I don't know how to force fetch() to use ipv4, will fetch select ipv6 as default?

Comment: ^ Put new information in the question please

Comment: As to how to do something with `fetch()`, now that you have that idea, could you research it?

Comment: Regarding your edit, are you sure that `application.propties` is correctly spelled in your post?

Answer (score 0):

::1 localhost is a way to shorten localhost IPv6 addresses.
A full string IPv6, like so `xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx` and this `::1 localhost` works the same way because they are the same.

I wouldn't advice disabling IPv6 addressing since many public web servers are using them by default now.

EDIT: You might want to disable IPv6 to test it.

Comment: Yes, I don't disable IPv6 `::1 localhost`, I can replace "localhost" with "127.0.0.1" in frontend code to fix this problem. But I still want to know the reason.

Comment: could you tell me how to disable ipv6 in nodejs? and is this the common solution for fetch a request in nodejs?